# MVC 5 EditorTemplate for Model renders with same id and name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editortemplates

I have Parent model "Receipt" and it has dictonary of objects as a property called `CustomControlDictionary` of class `CustomControlModel`. 
In my view i loop throuh each object in `CustomControlDictionary` property and call EditorTemplate. In the template i simply add label and textbox for my `CustomControlModel` object. 
When code renders html controls have same `id` and `name` attributes : `id="key_Value"` `name="key.Value"` . 
I did try using regualr arrays or lists instead of dictionary ,but with same result. Looking forward for any advise.

Model:

```
public class ReceiptModel 
{
    public ReceiptModel(){}
    public int ReceiptId { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptNumber { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, CustomControlModel> CustomControlDictionary{get; set; }
    // public List<CustomControlModel> CustomControlList { get; set; }
}


public class CustomControlModel 
{
    public CustomControlModel(){}
    public int CustomControlId{ get; set; }
    public string CustomControlName{ get; set; }
    public string LabelCaption{ get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
//View (@ReceiptModel):
@foreach (var key in Model.CustomControlDictionary )
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => key.Value,"CustomControlModel")
}
```

Editor Template:

```
@model EWMS_MVC.Classes.CustomControlModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomControlId)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomControlId, Model.LabelCaption)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomControlId, new { @Value = @Model.Value })
```

Rendered html has same `id` and `name` for all obects in `CustomControlDictionary` property of `ReceiptModel`:

```
<input id="key_Value_CustomControlId" name="key.Value.CustomControlId" type="hidden" value="201922" />//value here should be "id" of the input field
<label for="key_Value_CustomControlId">Receipt number:</label>
<input id="key_Value_CustomControlId" name="key.Value.CustomControlId" type="text" value="201922" />//value here should be "id" of the input field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach for this situation would be to avoid the HtmlHelper methods in your template and use html controls instead:

```
@model EWMS_MVC.Classes.CustomControlModel
<label>@Model.LabelCaption</label>
<input id="@Model.CustomControlId" name="@Model.CustomControlName" type="text" value="@Model.Value" />
```

Comment: Steve, i did switch to HTML controls and it wokrs as exptected. Now hoever i have a problem when I submit my view, "CustomControlDictionary" property of my "Reciept" model is null. Any idea on how make sure i get values back from  the view?

Comment: Try initialising it to a new instance in your model's constructor. And it can be a list if you have no use for the string index.

Comment: I did updated my model to use List instead of Dictionary and I initilized my CustomControlModel list in Model constructor. Still "CustomControlList" property of the "Reciept" model class is 0 length. Do i need to add anything to the editor template in order for "Receipt" model to store values in "CustomControlList" property?

Comment: Can you post your code for the controller and the full view code?